# how to set time interval for a specific function?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, notifications

Presently I have set time interval in such a way that every 1 seconds,a function is executed.The problem is that,i am displaying notification through this function.There are notification buttons in notification.When I click on the notification action button,mulitple windows are being open.I found out that it is because I have set Timer.But in my extension , timer is necessary in order to check the output of a server file everytime.Anyone please help me.Is there any other way to deal this problem
Here is my background.js

```
 var myNotificationID = null;
 var oldChromeVersion = !chrome.runtime;
    setInterval(function() {
   updateIcon();
      }, 1000); 

      function onInit() {   
           updateIcon();

         if (!oldChromeVersion) { 
       chrome.alarms.create('watchdog',{periodInMinutes:5,delayInMinutes:  0}); 
           }
       }

      function onAlarm(alarm) {
     if (alarm && alarm.name == 'watchdog') {
    onWatchdog();
    } 
    else {
      updateIcon();
         }
        }

   function onWatchdog() {
  chrome.alarms.get('refresh', function(alarm) {
   if (alarm) {
    console.log('Refresh alarm exists. Yay.');
      } 
     else {
    updateIcon();
  }
   });
   }

 if (oldChromeVersion) {
 updateIcon(); 
   onInit();
  } 

 else {
      chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(onInit);
        chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(onAlarm);
          }




    function updateIcon(){
      if(//something)
       //something

      else{

        chrome.notifications.create(
       'id1',{
       type: 'basic',
       iconUrl: '/calpine_not_logged_in.png',
       title: 'Warning : Attendance',
        message: 'Please mark your Attendance !',
       buttons: [{ title: 'Mark',
                        iconUrl: '/tick.jpg'
                  },{ title: 'Ignore',
                        iconUrl: '/cross.jpg'}],
       priority: 0},
       function(id) { myNotificationID = id;}
        ); 

    chrome.notifications.onButtonClicked.addListener(function(notifId, btnIdx) {
  if (notifId === myNotificationID) {
    if (btnIdx === 0) {
        window.open("http://www.calpinemate.com/");
    } else if (btnIdx === 1) {
       notification.close();
    }
    }
   });

 chrome.notifications.onClosed.addListener(function() {
  notification.close();
 });    
 }
  } }
  });
    }
   }
```

onInit();

Here i found out that,when i remove the delayInminutes and laso the set timeineterval it opens only one tab,as i want.But both of them are necessary to do continuous checking of a server file.because whole my operation is based on the server file output.Is there any way to cope with this problem.Is there any way to set time interval for only that function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with what you "suspect". The problem is that you add a listener for `chrome.notifications.onButtonClicked` events inside the `updateIcon()` function. So this is what happens:

- Every second you execute `updateIcon()`.
- Inside `updateIcon()` you set a **new** listener that listens for notification-buttons being clicked.
- So, after 1 second there will be 1 listener, after 2 seconds there will be 2 listeners, after *n* seconds there will be *n* listeners.
- When you click the button, **each** listener will catch the `onButtonClicked` event and open a new window. (So there will be so many windows as many seconds have elapsed since you loaded your extension.

#### How to fix this:

You need to create the listener **only once** (and not every second). To remove the following piece of code from inside the `updateIcon()` function:

```
chrome.notifications.onButtonClicked.addListener(function(notifId, btnIdx) {
    if (notifId === myNotificationID) {
        if (btnIdx === 0) {
            window.open("http://www.calpinemate.com/");
        } else if (btnIdx === 1) {
            notification.close();
        }
    }
});
```

And place it at the end of your background-page (just before `onInit();`). Make sure you don't place it inside any function.